# Limitation of members number in each group in people hub

Tags: sms, outlook, people

Is there any trick to avoid limitation of group members number (25 members) when I want to send email or SMS to more people. btw, this limit on people hub is there only in WP and not in regular web edition, so in this case my groups that I created 7 years ago are now useless

Comment: I think the limitation is there because it syncs every account of every user to show in his tile the latest news. Don't know if it matter when not pinned.